# How to update Event.target after props.function in child component is dispatched to redux-thunk onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In this e-commerce project, onClick "add to cart" should increment cart count, and change button textContent to "Remove from cart", a second onClick of the same element should decrement count and change textContent back to "Add to cart". I have shown 2 different conditional syntaxes that produce opposite behaviours.

```
function RenderBooks({book, updateCart}) {
    return(
        <Card className="allbooks">
            <CardBody>
            <Link to="/" style={{textDecoration:'none', color:'black'}} >
                <CardTitle><strong>{book.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={bookImg} alt="book image" />
                <CardText>{book.price}</CardText>
            </Link>
                <form>
                    <Button className="add-to-cart" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} color="link" 
                        onClick={(e, id) => updateCart(e, book.id)}
                    >
                        Add to cart
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );   
}
```

In the first condition of updateCart, event.target.textContent fires, but this.props.addToCart, which calls redux dispatch in the parent component, won't fire, while the reverse is the case in the else condition, that is, the dispatch function fires, and event.target doesn't. How may i get the dispatch function to fire after event.target.textContent fires, thanks in advance.

```
class Books extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.updateCart = this.updateCart.bind(this);
        
    }
    

    updateCart(event, id) {

        if (event.target.textContent === 'Add to cart') {
            event.target.textContent = 'Remove from cart';
            const count = this.props.cartcount.cartcount;
            () => {
                this.props.addToCart(id, count);
            }
        }
        else {
            event.target.textContent = 'Add to cart';
            let count = this.props.cartcount.cartcount;
            this.props.subtractFromCart(id, count);
        }
    }


    render() {

        const count = this.props.cartcount.cartcount;
        const book = this.props.books.books.map((book, index) => {
            return ( 
                <div key={index} className="col-8 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <RenderBooks book={book} updateCart={this.updateCart} />
                </div>     
            );
        });
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar dark expand="md" id="nav-books">
                    <div className="container">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to='/'>
                                    <BsArrowLeft />
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                        <NavbarBrand className="mc-auto logo" href="/">Soteria</NavbarBrand>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to='/'>
                                    <FiShoppingCart /> {count}
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
                <div className="container books">
                    <div className="row">
                        {book}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }   
}

export default Books;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in updateCart  method ```() => { target; this.props.addToCart(id, count);  }``` If it is an anonymous function or what? Please elaborate!

Comment: Thanks @Dolly. Scratch target; and it still makes no difference, this.props.addToCart(id, count) is dispatched in the parent/main component to a redux-thunk in ActionCreators, which then dispatches to the reducer that updates count and exports to configureStore. Count is updated, but event.textContent = "Remove from cart" doesn't update, though it does in console.log. Remove the props.function dispatch, and event.textContent fires. From research so far, this seems to be the behaviour of redux-thunk, but can't say for sure.

Comment: Hi @Uwem This should work. Check a minimal reproduction I created as per your scenario https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-cookies-8z5y5?file=/index.js

Comment: Thanks @Dolly, your implementation works, but i needed to achieve that behaviour after sending props.addToCart() to redux-thunk, which doesn't happen because redux-thunk is synchronous as i would learn, so the event listener already bubbles off by the time the store is updated. Seeing event.persist() in your implementation, i wonder if that will persist the event till when store updates, but i have solved the problem with an intuitive solution by explicitly updating the UI in RenderBooks() if store is updated..

Comment: @Dolly I will post the solution. I may have or may have not provided enough context, but thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that redux-thunk is synchronous, so the event listener is lost by the time the store is updated. So i eventually thought up what is an intuitive react-redux solution by adding itemids param, an array that stores clicked items ids, and updating the UI in RenderBooks() with ternary operators;

```
function RenderBooks({book, itemids, updateCart}) {
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardBody>
            <Link to="/" style={{textDecoration:'none', color:'black'}} >
                <CardTitle><strong>{book.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={bookImg} alt="book image" />
                <CardText>{book.price}</CardText>
            </Link>
                    {
                        itemids.length != 0 ?
                            itemids.includes(book.id) ?
                                <Button onClick={(e, id) => updateCart(e, book.id)}>
                                    Remove from cart
                                </Button>
                            :
                                <Button onClick={(e, id) => updateCart(e, book.id)}>
                                    Add to cart
                                </Button>
                        :
                        
                        <Button onClick={(e, id) => updateCart(e, book.id)}>
                            Add to cart
                        </Button>       
                    }
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
    );   
}
```

So in updateCart, i only use event.target.textContent to determine which props.function to  call.

```
class Books extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.updateCart = this.updateCart.bind(this);
    }


    updateCart(event, id) {

        let target = event.target.textContent;

        if (target === 'Add to cart') {
                        
            this.props.addToCart(id)

        }
        else {
            
            this.props.subtractFromCart(id);
        }
    }


    render() {

        const book = this.props.books.books.map((book, index) => {
            return ( 
                <div key={index} className="col-8 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <RenderBooks book={book} itemids={this.props.itemids}       
                                 updateCart={this.updateCart} 
                    />
                </div>     
            );
        });
        
        return (
            <div>                  
                <div className="container books">
                    <div className="row">
                        {book}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }   
}
export default Books;
```